# Scope of a function as variable attribution to a .click jQuery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, click

The script in JavaScript/jQuery :

```
// Creation of the variables

var foo = [];
foo.functionForClick = function(){ alert('foo'); }

var bar = [];
bar.functionForClick = function(){ alert('bar'); }

// Attribution of the function to the button
var button;

// button foo 
button = foo;
$('#buttonFoo').click(function(){button.functionForClick()});

// button bar, I MUST use the same 'button' variable, 
// it's in the script (it's in a for loop...)  
button = bar;
$('#buttonBar').click(function(){button.functionForClick();});
```

HTML code

```
<button id="buttonFoo">
Show Foo
</button>

<button id="buttonBar">
Show Bar
</button>
```

Why, after execution of the script (which reproduces a more complicated script of a web app I'm coding), the "Show Foo" button alert "bar"?

Any solution?

You can have a look of the problem here:

**https://jsfiddle.net/hdye648f/**

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  button.functionForClick is already a function, so no need to wrap it in the anonymous function.  The extra anonymous function is causing `button` to be resolved when the function executes, rather than when the function is defined.

Instead of

```
$('#buttonFoo').click(function(){button.functionForClick()});
```

do

```
$('#buttonFoo').click(button.functionForClick);
```

Comment: Perfect ! I see now where was the problem...

Thanks !